# Why can't I see players on the map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had set up a Minecraft 1.8.8 server and play together with a friend on this server. All clients and the server are Vanilla, no mods installed.

I had created Map#6 some time ago, and I copied it for my friend. It worked for some time that we both could see each other.

A few days ago, this feature broke. I can't see my friend on my map. But he can see me. The maps are identical, both Map#6.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe your friend is in the spectator gamemode?

Comment: Did it just happen? Or is there anything big that you did which may trigger this? Check if your friend is not in Spectator Mode (Gamemode 3), he does not have invisibility effect (by doing `/effect <friend name> clear`), or similar factors that make you unable to see him but not the other way around.

Comment: No, my friend was not in Gamemode 3 (not an OP). The map worked a week later, without an update of the client or server (1.8.8) - it seemed to be a glitch. We also discovered a glitch that the arrows on the map stop moving after we were in the Nether - after a reconnect to the server, the arrows on the map move again. Are you aware of these map-bugs in 1.8.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

you most likely cannot see players on the map because you aren't using a locator map.  By default when you create a map it will no longer show your location or player locations.  If you combine the map with a compass in the crafting table it will become a locator map and give these player locations.

Answer (score 0):

There may just be a glitch, and you will have to reload. Sometimes if your Wi-fi isn't good, then you won't be able to connect and see players. There could have been an update while you were gone and that could cause the game to glitch. Otherwise just reload or logout and log back in.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, when there are two players on a map and one cannot see the other, the person who is invisible will have to re-log and this works most of the time.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. But I fixed it by reloading my game. Also since he could see you, try to ask him to reload his game as well. It worked for me. Hope i helped and hope you get it fixed.☺

Comment: Stop trying to edit my answers!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade.  This website works very differently from most.  I suggest you take the tour:  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour, then you'll understand why your answer got edited.

Answer (score -2):

**Invisible players will not show up on maps.**  Try to see someone without invisibility or a Bukkit plugin or a plugin bug or an error. It happened to me as well.